# Landsat-QA-ArcGIS-Toolbox Problem

Tags: arcmap, landsat-8

I am using the following toolbox to remove some anomalous pixels from my image (Landsat 8 C2L2). This tool doesn't work on ArcGIS Pro but it works on ArcMap 10.3 instead. The problem is that, when I execute **Extract QA Bands** I get nothing as a result (I am choosing a desired location and a name but no file is being generated). On the other hand, ArcMap 10.3 says that the procedure completed successfully. How can I solve this problem?

**Link for QA_Toolbox: https://code.usgs.gov/espa/landsat-qa-arcgis-toolbox**

**Image 1: Decode QA**
[image]
**Image 2: Decode QA Result**
[image]
**Image 3: Extracting QA Bands**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your final image is not showing the output path and the green dot indicates its a mandatory parameter, so the tool shouldn't even run until you provide a value, which of cause we cant see.

Comment: @Hornbydd no it’s not that, as I explain I choose a name and a file but nothing happens, event if ArcMap says that operation completed successfully. I will upload new screenshots. Anyway do you know any alternative that I can use?

Comment: @Hornbydd I uploaded some new images.

Comment: Suggest you look at the [caveats](https://code.usgs.gov/espa/landsat-qa-arcgis-toolbox#tool-extract-qa-bands) in the link you provide, you state in your question you are using 10.3.

Comment: @Hornbydd I guess it doesn't work on previous versions. Could you suggest me an alternative? I mean what can I use instead of these tools?

Comment: Looks like you might have background processing turned on. Try turning that off in the GP Settings and run the tool again. Any difference?

Comment: I just skimmed the code in https://code.usgs.gov/espa/landsat-qa-arcgis-toolbox/-/blob/master/Scripts/extract_bands.py (assuming that's the tool you're using), and while 10.3 is a long time ago, nothing stands out that would require 10.4 and not 10.3. I only see a couple simple tools (CON, Build Raster Attribute Table)

Comment: @KHibma I turned it off, but the problem still exists. Could you suggest me another way to do the same thing using a different tool?